# getting result from AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to get the result from the AsyncTask to another class. I am using interface to achieve this. I doing the same procedure in another module and it was working good but I fail to identify the issue in this case...
I'm calling like this from another class.

```
GroupDetails gd=new GroupDetails();
groups=gd.getGroupList("email");




public class GroupDetails implements AsyncResponse {
    String result;
    String[] groupList;

    public String getGroupList(String userEmail){

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_email", userEmail));
        PhpConnect phpcon=new PhpConnect("http://www.pinnacle2k14.com/letsmeet/get_group.php",postParameters);
        phpcon.delegate=this;
        phpcon.execute();
        result="hello"
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void processFinish(String output) { //this method not functioning why?
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        result="hello";
        //groupList=output.split(",");


    }

}
```

**PhpConnect.php**

```
public class PhpConnect extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    String url1;
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters1;

    public PhpConnect(String url,ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters){
        url1=url;
        postParameters1=postParameters;

    }
    public PhpConnect() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    String response;
    public AsyncResponse delegate=null;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost(url1,postParameters1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            response=e.toString();
        }
        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        delegate.processFinish(result);
    }


}
```

**AsynResponse interface**

```
public interface AsyncResponse {
    void processFinish(String output);

}
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue?

Comment: @curtisLoew the processFinish method in GroupDetails not working

Comment: Should the `getGroupList` method return the String that is being processed in the `PhpConnect` async task?

Comment: Also, you are aware you're not assigning the `processFinish` method parameter `output` to the `result`, right?

Comment: @crutisLoew what i say is that method never executes...sorry  if I'm repeating the question...I don't understand what you say...

Answer (score 0):

You know you can do

```
PhpConnect phpcon=new PhpConnect("http://www.pinnacle2k14.com/letsmeet/get_group.php",postParameters) {

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(String result) {

    //DO YOUR STUFF

    }

};

phpcon.execute();
```

This way you can save the callback.

Comment: Even this is not working. I tried assigning result1="hello" inside the onPostExecute method as you mentioned above. Not working...but when i initialize result1="hello" outside the method and it is working

Comment: You are doing it wrong. What you get in onPostExecute is the result from your doInBackground() operation. In doInBackground() you are doing result="hello"; return result; In onPostExecute(String output) output contains the value of result. So if you do Log.i("Result",result) in onPostExecute(String result), you will see it logs your "Hello" String. You are calculating your result String in doInBackground, then return it, it gets passed to onPostExecute and there you can grab it to use it in the UI Thread. That's the way an AsyncTask works.